# Creating the Pipe | with a german Keyboard Layout in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-12.04, pipeline

I tried to make the `pipe` in `ubuntu` but it  didn't work. On a german layout it's done by holding <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>the bracket key above <></kbd>. In `Ubuntu` it doesn't work and I already tried to choose different keyboard layouts by entering this to the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Is there anyone who made it?

Comment: was the answer helpful for you?

Comment: hey, just took a break.  sorry, but it didn't work...at least for me.

Comment: what happened if you try `right alt ^` or `ctrl left alt ^`?

Comment: didn't help either. i tried a lot :(   i will come back to this problem tomorrow and check more

Comment: none of these or below answer didn't helped me, I could resolve the issue using command **setxkbmap us** https://superuser.com/a/840405

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
ctrl left alt Q = @
ctrl left alt ß = \
ctrl left alt ^ = |
ctrl left alt E = €
```

or:

```
right alt Q = @
right alt ß = \
right alt ^ = |
right alt E = €
```